# Java var type inference on generic parameter type

Tags: java, generics, lambda, type-inference

I'm having a merge-Function for a stream collector and trying to make it generical applicable. Since the lambda is accepting var as parameter type and the resulting type is of BinaryOperator, I'm trying to get something like BinaryOperator<?> or similar.

```
BinaryOperator<InsertYourFavouriteType> rejectNewValueAndWarn = (oldValue, newValue ) -> {
            LOGGER.warn( "Old value already present in map, rejecting to collect new value" );
            LOGGER.warn( "Old value:" + oldValue );
            LOGGER.warn( "New value:" + newValue );
            return oldValue;
        };
```

This is already pretty generic applicable, but I want to get rid of the explicit type in the generics parameter.

Comment: Then `rejectNewValueAndWarn` should be declared in a context (a generic class or a generic method) that allows `InsertYourFavouriteType` to be typed using a type variable. Maybe this is an XY problem, please explain what you're trying to do with `rejectNewValueAndWarn`.

Comment: @Lino Oh I see. OP is trying to use it as the combiner parameter of `collect`.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66583538/5133585)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that directly<sup>1</sup> with a variable, but it is entirely possible using a method:

```java
public final class Rejecter {
    public static <T> T rejectNewValueAndWarn(T oldValue, T newValue) {
        LOGGER.warn("Old value already present in map, rejecting to collect new value");
        LOGGER.warn("Old value:" + oldValue);
        LOGGER.warn("New value:" + newValue);
        return oldValue;
    }
}
```

Then you can use method references to reference the method directly:

```
Map<A, B> map = whatever.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        ..., // your key mapper
        ..., // your value mapper
        Rejecter::rejectNewValueAndWarn // the merge function
    ));
```

<sup>1</sup> You could define the generic parameter to be either `?` or `Object`, but then you would need casts for every usage, like `(BinaryOperator<SomeType>) rejectNewValueAndWarn`, which effectively eliminates the whole purpose of extracting this logic into a common place.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I came up with almost the same solution - so yours looks pretty good to me :-D

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after the hint with the generics type as type parameter I came up with having a mergefunction defined as follows:

```
static < K > BinaryOperator< K > mergeFunction()
    {
        BinaryOperator< K > rejectNewValueAndWarn = ( oldValue, newValue ) -> {
            LOGGER.warn( "Old value already present in map, rejecting to collect new value" );
            LOGGER.warn( "Old value:" + oldValue );
            LOGGER.warn( "New value:" + newValue );
            return oldValue;
        };
        return rejectNewValueAndWarn;
    }
```

```
blablaList.
            .stream()
            .collect( Collectors.toMap( AbstractDto::getName, Function.identity(), mergeFunction() ) );
```

Comment: You should just return the lambda directly, and you should rename the method to `rejectNewValueAndWarn`, so the effect is "documented" wherever it is used.